# Align a \hrule with the right side of the page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\hrule width 2cm  height 3.5pt\relax

\end{document}
```

Given a test document such as the above, how does one align the \hrule with the right side of the page? I have the tried 'flush' and 'fill' options, but to no avail.

Comment: Use the LaTeX version: `\raggedleft\rule{2cm}{3.5pt} `.

Comment: Instead of `\hrule`, use `\rule`. Then you can try `\leavevmode\hfill\rule{2cm}{3.5pt}`.

Comment: Is there any solution that does involve \hrule?

Comment: \hrule will be better for the document I'm compiling

Comment: why will it be better? (it is not a latex command at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\hrule` is not a latex command and does not react to `raggedleft` or `centering` or any other latex formatting constructs. You should use `\rule`. However you ask in comments whether `\hrule` can be made to work, I offer this as one possibility which avoids staring a new paragraph (which is the only reason I could think of for why you would want to avoid using the latex construct)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\moveright\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm\vbox{%
\hrule width 2cm  height 3.5pt\relax}

\end{document}
```